# Convertir .ui a .py Genera Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, rutas

He tratado de generar un script de python con PyQt5 sin embargo al tratar de convertirlo me genera un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya revise el PATH para confirmar que la variable de entorno se encuentre ahi, tambien trate cambiar de version de python a la version 3.3 , 3.6 y arroja el mismo resultado.

Comment: Por lo que te dice el error, el sistema no está pudiendo encontrar un `python.exe` en la ruta `c:\Python35`, Si pruebas ejecutar `c:\Python35\python` que ocurre?